# configuring odoo for vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, odoo

i want to include odoo into my vscode and according to the youtube video i'm following i'm supposed to configure one/any of the server files which is in python but the launch.json file does not open up

tried running it without debugging to see what might happen, and i also checked through the comments of the videos i used and saw that it wasn't an issue anyone hadn't faced before but no solution was given on how to go about solving it

Answer (score 0):

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Odoo",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/odoo/odoo-bin",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "justMyCode": true,
        "args": [
            "--addons-path=./odoo/addons,./enterprise/",
            "-d", "bug_fix16",
            "--dev","xml,qweb",
            "-i","purchase_requisition",
            "--test-tags",".test_08_purchase_requisition_sequence",
            "--smtp=localhost",
            "--smtp-port=1025",
            "--limit-time-real", "1200",
            "--max-cron-threads", "8",
        ]
    }
]
```